# How to accept terminal input immediately after displaying audio in Colab?

Tags: audio, terminal, google-colaboratory, display

I'm trying to write a function in Colab that plays a short audio file, and then displays a text box for the user to type in a response. However, when I try the following code, the audio file plays normally but the input text box is not displayed. Any idea how to get this to work?

```
import IPython
audio = IPython.display.Audio('test.wav', autoplay=True)
display(audio)
input('User input goes here: ')
```

Answer (score -1):

check out this reported bug:

https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/2889

this is the same issue. The bug is still open but known to colab developers.

Comment: For asking questions (this is more or less "do you think that this is the same?") comments should be used, for which you lack the privilege. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead Please either delete this post or [edit] it to turn it into an answer with a solution according to [answer].